# How can I disable third-party event handlers on a button?

Tags: javascript, ajax, addeventlistener

So this is a multi-part question...

1) I am adding an event listener to a form button so that I can control the up-coming steps. The issue is, that I am working on an e-comm platform that has a bunch of their own event listeners when a user clicks on the button. How can I stop/kill all the "built-in" event listeners and ajax requests? I just want to have my custom one take over. I've tried the prevent default method but doesn't seem to be killing the built functions.

2) How I can track down all the event listeners or ajax requests that are being fired on the button click? I was looking through the network tab in the console, but I don't see the file in which I am creating an event listener outputting a console log. I see the console log, but not the call to the file in the network tab.

Keep in mind this is experimental and I won't be omitting the core functionality - just for debugging and experimenting purposes.

Thanks a lot,

Sergio

Comment: You want the Elements tab, and then Event Listeners in the side panel.

Comment: @isherwood what should I be doing / looking for in the Event Listeners side panel? I see all the event listeners but nothing happens when I click the submit button.